# Can JProfiler tell me how long queries are taking?

Tags: performance, jprofiler

Wouldn't it be nice if I could drill down into the JProfiler CPU View, and find a percentage of time running a certain query against the database?  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

The call tree in JProfiler shows JDBC queries with the default settings:

[image]

If this is not the case, open the session settings, go to the probe settings, select the JDBC probe and ensure that "Enabled", "Record on startup" and "Annotate JDBC calls in call tree" are selected:

[image]

Another way to look at JDBC query strings is the "hot spot" view of the JDBC probe:

[image]